# How can I generate random numbers without using Math.random()?

Tags: javascript

Looking for Javascript program. Without using Math.random() method in Javascript. How do generate random no.

Comment: Obligatory https://xkcd.com/221/ And with more seriousness, what kind of "random" do you need? Does it just need to be unique in a dozen of tries? Does it need to be cryptographically safe random? etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getTime()` for that like that, if length doesn't matter for your, if it does, use `.slice()` method but before using it convert it in string using `.toString()`

```js
const randomNumber = parseInt(new Date().getTime())
console.log(randomNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

use timestamp

```
Math.floor(Date.now() /1000);
```

Without `Math` library

```
Date.now() /1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for 3 digit random number

```
console.log((new Date().getMilliseconds()));
```

Comment: Also you can use code posted by @callmenikk for long numbers.